# WebAPI Return JSON array with root node

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am working with webaip odata where I need to get the product details which i am able to archive in fiddler and postman.But I am not able to change a field value.
Please go through the Image of my result set[image] to understand the my requirement properly.

The Code what I am following is:

```
[HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("Product")]
    public IQueryable<BEProduct> GetProduct()
    {           
        return BOProduct.GetProduct().AsQueryable();
    }




public partial class BEProduct
{        
    [Key]
    public short ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

I saw an example [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007512/webapi-return-json-array-without-root-node) which exactly matches with my requirement, but not able to implement the same.Can someone please help me to Short this out.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015104/how-to-convert-httpresponsemessage-having-odata-to-a-c-sharp-object/40015329#40015329

Comment: Hello Amit, I thing you didn't got my requirement clearly.I just want to show  the result set along with a customized root node by using the above model(Controller and the entity)

Comment: I had a similar issue where I used a wrapper class and didn't want it in the JSON. This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47137704/1393400